# (Simple) Trigonometric Identity: $\frac1{\sin x\cos x } = \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}$

Tags: trigonometry

Part of a bigger question requires me to prove this trigonometric identity $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin x\cos x } =  \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}$$ Can someone shows me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Is the left hand side $\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}?$

Comment: @jnh Yes it will be visible soon

Comment: My edit was wrong again, it should be $\sec^2 x$ who approved it ?

Comment: @PandaBear I don't know who approved it, but I fixed it now.

Answer (score 6):

Simplify the right hand side:  $$\dfrac{\sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}=\dfrac{\;\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\;}{\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}=\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos^2(x)}=\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$